# React 18 / RTK Query error: could not find react-redux context value. App *is* already wrapped in a Provider

Tags: reactjs, redux, react-redux, rtk-query, react-18

For some reason I've started getting the above error after I updated React to v18. Is React 18 not compatible with RTK Query? I've tested this with normal redux slice and it works without issue but for some reason I get this error when I try to use RTK Query.

Any help trying to troubleshoot this would be much appreciated because I'm at a loss.

[image]

index.tsx

```
import ReactDOM from "react-dom/client";
import App from "./App";
import { Provider } from "react-redux"; 
import { store } from "./store/store";
const container = document.getElementById("root") as HTMLElement;

const rootContainer = ReactDOM.createRoot(container);

rootContainer.render(
  <Provider store={store}>
    <App />
  </Provider>
);
```

store.tsx

```
import { configureStore, Store } from '@reduxjs/toolkit'
// Or from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query/react'
import { setupListeners } from '@reduxjs/toolkit/query'
import { pokemonApi } from './services/pokemon'

export const store: Store = configureStore({
  reducer: {
    // Add the generated reducer as a specific top-level slice
    [pokemonApi.reducerPath]: pokemonApi.reducer,
  },
  // Adding the api middleware enables caching, invalidation, polling,
  // and other useful features of `rtk-query`.
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware().concat(pokemonApi.middleware),
})

// optional, but required for refetchOnFocus/refetchOnReconnect behaviors
// see `setupListeners` docs - takes an optional callback as the 2nd arg for customization
setupListeners(store.dispatch)
```

App.tsx

```
import { DefaultLayout } from "@components/layout/DefaultLayout";
import { Route, Routes, BrowserRouter } from "react-router-dom";
import HomePage from "@components/home/HomePage";
import SignUpPage from "@components/authentication/SignUpPage";
import LoginPage from "@components/authentication/LoginPage";
import BooksPage from "@components/books/BooksPage";
import { AppContextsProvider } from "@contexts/AppContexts";

const App = () => {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <AppContextsProvider>
        <DefaultLayout>
          <Routes>
            <Route path="/" element={<HomePage />} />
            <Route path="/login" element={<LoginPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/signup" element={<SignUpPage />}></Route>
            <Route path="/books" element={<BooksPage />}></Route> 
          </Routes>
        </DefaultLayout>
      </AppContextsProvider>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
};

export default App;
```

BooksPage.tsx

```
import { useGetPokemonByNameQuery } from "@store/services/pokemon";

const BooksPage = () => {
  const { data, error, isLoading } = useGetPokemonByNameQuery("bulbasaur");
  console.log("data", data);
  return (
    <div>
      <div>BooksPage</div>
    </div>
  );
};

export default BooksPage;
```

package.json

```
"dependencies": {
     ...
    "@redux-devtools/extension": "^3.2.2",
    "@reduxjs/toolkit": "^1.8.2",
    "@types/react": "^18.0.14",
    "@types/react-dom": "^18.0.5",
    "react": "^18.2.0",=
    "react-dom": "^18.2.0",
    "react-redux": "^8.0.2",
    "react-router-dom": "^6.2.2",
    ...
  },
```

Comment: Your import seems to be broken, `import { store } from./store/store";` is that the case?

Comment: Think that's just a copying error. Still get same error. Updated question.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not 100% sure but it seems the issue was, in fact, relatated to the `<AppContextsProvider>` component which contains a `styled-components` `ThemeProvider` component. This component was quitely throwing errors related to:

https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/issues/59765

I followed the solution in that thread and added the following to package.json:

```
"resolutions": {
    ...
    "@types/react": "17.0.43",
    "@types/react-dom": "17.0.43"
  },
```

After running yarn install and re-starting everything the page renders without any errors and RTK Query hooks run as expected.